# How to subset a list of vectors based on a vector of indexes?

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to use `purrr` to subset the elements from this list

```
u <- list(a=1:10, b=1:10)
```

using `maxCol` as the highest bound for a vector of indexes starting from 1. For example, suppose that

```
maxCol <- c(6L, 3L)
```

Then the output should look like

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

$b
[1] 1 2 3
```

In fact, I want to keep all the values from position 1 to position 6 from `a`, and from position 1 to 3 from `b`.
I know how to do it with a loop but I would like to use `purrr` . For example, I thought something like this would work but it didn't:

```
map2(u, maxRow, u[1:maxCol])
```

Comment: Staying with your syntax, you could use `map2(u, maxCol, ~.x[1:.y])`, but this seems much more convoluted than simply using `head`.

Comment: @ThomasK thanks I also come up with the same once @ChiPak answered. It actually looked easier to me 'cause I completely forgot about the argument `n` in `head()`, and it's more generalizable too if I didn't want to start from 1 (thus I dare to say superior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
map2(u,maxCol,head)
```

Output

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

$b
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Also `map2(.x=u, .y=maxCol, .f= ~ .x[1:.y])`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(head, u, n = maxCol)
```